# How to show flask foreign key field in modelform with readable display dropdown?

Tags: foreign-keys, flask-sqlalchemy, dropdown, flask-wtforms, modelform

I have a one to many and many to many relationship in my models. I'm using `wtforms_alchemy` `ModelForm` to create the forms, but the `ForeignKey` field is not showing up as a drop down field, also it's showing the integers as values in them. I tried referencing similar questions and tried the answers, like, I put `__str__()` as well as `__repr__()` functions in them so that they return some readable and meaningful string in the drop down but that didn't happen. Does anyone have any idea of how else can I do it?

[image]

Models.py-

```
class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'))

    def __init__(self, name, location=None):
        self.name = name
        if location:
            self.location_id = location.id

    def __repr__(self):
        warehouse = Location.query.filter_by(id = self.location_id).first()
        qty = warehouse.get_product_quantity(self.name)
        return '{0}-{1}-{2}'.format(self.name, warehouse.name, qty)

class Location(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    products = db.relationship('Product', backref='warehouse')

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Location-{0}'.format(self.name)

class Movement(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    from_location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("location.id"))
    to_location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("location.id"))
    from_location = db.relationship(Location, lazy='joined', foreign_keys=[from_location_id], backref='from_location')
    to_location = db.relationship(Location, lazy='joined', foreign_keys=[to_location_id], backref='to_location')
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'))
    product = db.relationship(Product, backref='movements')
    qty = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

forms.py -

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm, Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        include = ['name']

class LocationForm(ModelForm, Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        include = ['name']

class MovementForm(ModelForm, Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Movement
        include = ['from_location_id', 'to_location_id', 'product_id', 'qty']
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Id's are integers the WTForm-ALchemy will convert the form field to integer field you can see this [here](http://[here]:%20https://wtforms-alchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/column_conversion.html#basic-type-conversion)

So, you can force to use select field as explained [here](https://wtforms-alchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html#forcing-the-use-of-selectfield)

If do you want some more readable you can use the [QuerySelectField](https://wtforms-alchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#wtforms_alchemy.fields.QuerySelectField).

```
class MovementForm(ModelForm, Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Movement

    product = QuerySelectField(
        query_factory=lambda: Product.query.all(),
        get_pk=lambda a: a.id,
        get_label=lambda a: a.name,
        allow_blank=False,
    )
```

If you prefer, you can use the view/route to query and pass to the form the options.

```
def movement_new():
    movement = Movement()
    form = MovementForm(obj=movement)

    products = [(c.id, c.name) for c in Product.query.all()]
    form.product_id.choices = products
    ...
```

Then on MovementForm

```
class MovementForm(ModelForm, Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Movement    ---> note tha the include was removed

    product_id = SelectField('Product', coerce=int)
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the select options from your route function

Example using your models and forms:

```
@app.route('/movement/<movement_id>')
def edit_movement(movement_id):
    products = db.engine.execute("select id, product_name from products")
    form.product.choices = [(p.id, p.product_name) for p in products]
    return render_template('movement.html', movement_id=movement_id, form=form)
```